# How to create custom color picker drop down using jQuery UI select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'v been trying to create a custom drop down that will contain color name along with the color chip(shade of the color). The drop down would be dynamically populated by the options that I would provide as input in the form of array of colors. 
Basically, What I am trying to achieve is this:
[image: target to achieve]

So, I used jQuery UI selectmenu plugin which provides an option to put 'icons' along with the text in the drop down: [selectmenu icon](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render). I am planning to replace icons with the color chip. 
I am planning to use `_renderItem` of `selectmenu` to do this and have so far achieved this:
[[image: target achieved so far[3]] 
The color of font here is the color of color chip that I want to be displayed along with the text. I do get the rgb value of color. Here is the implementation so far:

```
$.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                console.log(item);
                var li = $("<li>")
                    .css("color", "#"+item.value); //changing color with item.value

                if (item.disabled) {
                    li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                }

                this._setText(li, item.label);

                return li.appendTo(ul);
            }
        });



 $("#DropDownID")
            .iconselectmenu()
            .iconselectmenu("menuWidget");

for (var i = 0; i < Color.Data.length; i++) {
                $("#DropDownID").append($("<option></option>").val(Color.Data[i].RgbValue).html(Color.Data[i].ColorName));
            }
```

Can you help me in achieving the color chip and text format in the drop down as mentioned earlier by replacing the current javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track by using renderItem. Essentially, all that is left is adding the color chip to the li element. You can either add an icon/image or add another html element. In the example I create I simply added a span to the li that would act as the color chip.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {

      console.log(item);
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>");

      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }

      $("<span>", {
          style: "background-color: #" + item.value,
          "class": "ui-color-chip"
        })
        .appendTo(wrapper);
      wrapper.append(item.label);

      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#DropDownID")
    .selectmenu()
    .selectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons customicons");

  var Color = {
    Data: [

      {
        RgbValue: 'ff0000',
        ColorName: 'Red'
      }, {
        RgbValue: '008000',
        ColorName: 'Green'
      },
    ]
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < Color.Data.length; i++) {
    $("#DropDownID").append($("<option></option>").val(Color.Data[i].RgbValue).html(Color.Data[i].ColorName)  );
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-color-chip {
  height: 12px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 1em;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select name="DropDownID" id="DropDownID"></select>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm bro! Thank you!